# LibreOffice Writer strikethrough color

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, text-formatting

There seems to be no setting for the strikethrough color in LibreOffice Writer 4.4.7.2. For undelining and overlining there is such an option.

Is it somehow possible to change that color? I'd like to have red strikethrough.

What is the reasoning behind not having that option?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is not possible.  The API shows `CharOverlineColor` and `CharUnderlineColor` but only [these options](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/awt/FontStrikeout.html) for strikeout.

If the text is changed to red, then the strikeout line will be red as well.

A workaround for black text with red strikeout is to draw a red line:

1. `View -> Toolbars -> Drawing`.  Use the `Line` tool.
2. Draw a line over the word, and set the color to red.  Set the width to 1.0 to make it thicker.
3. Right-click on the line and select `Position and Size`.  Anchor `To character`.  Position Horizontal: `From left` by 0.00 to `Character`.  Vertical: `Center` to `Character`.  Then press OK.
4. Drag the anchor icon to the first character in the word.
5. **UPDATED ANSWER**: Also under `Position and Size`, check Protect: `Position`.  This prevents the line from being accidentally dragged to the wrong place.  However the anchor can still be moved.

The result looks like this:

[image: red strikeout line]

Comment: Good workaround, although I have to say it's still not very convenient. If the word moves, the line will be at the wrong position; One can still move the line up and down, which could happen accidentally and then it's not in the vertical middle anymore; it does not snap to characters, as if it was semantically connected to them ...
Probably the best one can do in LO Writer at the time being, though : /

Comment: Did you set the anchor type `To character` and then move the anchor to the word?  That should cause the line to move when the character moves, for example if another word is added before it.  However there are other limitations such as not resizing if the word changes length.  Regarding accidentally moving, see my edited answer.

Comment: Even if I set the anchor type `to character` it does not move with a word when I add words or characters before it. LO Version: `4.4.7.2`. Maybe in LO 5 that works. To protect the position only serves to force me to unprotect it again, to move it with a word. It would be better i I could lock only the vertical position, or force the line to stay on the lines of text, like on a horizontal grid, but it's only possible to lock the whole position. Also I think locking the position would even disable moving with a word if that was what happened with anchoring to character.

Comment: I used version 5.1.0.3, and it sounds like it works better than 4.4.7.2.  So it may be worth the effort to upgrade.

Comment: Had some trouble with black text on dark grey background for LO GUI elements with the downloaded up to date version, but since I switched to a brighter theme, I can try a newer version too. Did you find any way of making the horizontal lines exactly as long as the characters they shall strike through? The perfectionist in me wants the lines to be as long as the ones you get from strikethrough, or only unnoticably different length.

Comment: I did not find a way to make the length exactly right.  However it can be made very close by zooming in more than 200% when drawing the line.

Comment: Another problem with the approach is, that it is not manageable with styles. Who zooms in so far only to be able to draw a line like that and then having to do all these settings for one single word? Imagine you have a whole essay you want to treat ... Hours upon hours of clicky-work there. No, I think I'll just wait for LO to support color of strikethrough.